# Applying a transformation to a list of images in parallel

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to apply the same transformation (HOGs/blurring) to each image in a list in parallel. The images are numpy ndarrays imported using cv2.imread and saved to a list.

Currently when I pass the list of images to my function a single entry in the array appears to be passed, i.e. one pixel in the image as opposed to a whole image. Can you advise how to pass an entire array/image to each worker in the pool?

Thanks!

```py
# imports
from functools import partial
from skimage.feature import hog
from multiprocessing import Pool

def findhog(image):
    return hog(image, visualise=True)[1] # hog returns two things, only return the visualisation

with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    hogs = pool.map(findhog, listofimages)
```

Comment: What you posted looks correct. Did you check `listofimages` is what you expected?

Comment: I was also using partial()  but didn't include that because I thought that was correct. It turns out that's where the issue was...